# NodeJS / express-session - persist session variables between routes

Tags: node.js, express, session, session-variables, express-session

I am trying to set up session variables that would persist between routes.

Problem is, that doesn't seem to happen. When I make a post request, the session variable is updated accordingly - however when trying a different get route via postman (and checking console output), the variable is empty

Here's the code:

```
const express = require('express')
const session = require('express-session')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')

const app = express()

app.use(session({
    secret: 'test one',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    name: "mycookiesession",
    cookie: { secure: false }
}))

let mySession

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    mySession = req.session
    mySession.basket = []
    next()
})

app.get('/basket', function (req, res) {
    console.log(mySession.basket)
    res.send(mySession.basket)
})

app.post('/basket/add', function (req, res) {
    mySession.basket = [0, 1, 2]
    console.log(mySession.basket)
    res.send('null')
    res.status(201).end()
})

app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('Example app listening')
})
```

What am I doing wrong? I just need to see the value added to the basket by post:basket/add when retrieving the var in the get:basket route

Cheers

Comment: Your server must handle many requests in parallel, but your global variable `mySession` exists only _once_. This cannot work, remove this global variable and use `req.session` instead. And you cannot say `res.status(...)` _after_ `res.send(...)`.

Comment: Thanks, I did as suggested - the results is the same. 

get /basket shows empty to start with (OK)

post /basket/add shows all good and I can see the basket variable updated correctly (OK)

requesting get /basket again however, shows basket as empty (wrong)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a middleware the sets `basket = []` in your session for *every* incoming request. This middleware is executed for every request, because the `app.use(function ...)` command does not specify a path.

Comment: That's it!:) I have been resetting my basket. Silly me!